# Specialize behaviors of super and subscript for self defined commands

Tags: macros

I have defined a few commands like

```
\newcommand{\expec}[1]{\mathbb E\left[#1\right]}
```

This command is really useful for me. However, now I need to write expectation wrt to random variables which I would write as

```
\mathbb E_{X\sim F}\left[g(X)\right]
```

My question is, can I overload the `_` operator for `\expec` so that `\expec_{1}{2}` renders like `\mathbb E_{1}\left[2\right]`

I want to avoid redefining a new command (with 2 parameters) since I would eventually need to work with superscripts as well and then I'll need a total of 4 new commands.

I tried using optional arguments using `ifthenelse` but that is not very good since if I use that, I'll have to change all the previous instances of `\expec` to include one set of empty curly brackets.

I realize overloading is probably not the best idea, so I'm open to other ideas as well

Comment: use the `e` argument type for `\NewDocumentCommand` (note it should be `\mathbb{E}` avoid omitting the braces. It would also be better to avoid `left` and `right` in most cases (or use mleftright package or mathtoold declarepaireddelimiter to avoid problems with spacing

Comment: Please note that while it's (of course!) ok to upvote good answers immediately, site guidelines suggest waiting at least several hours, and ideally a day or two, before 'accepting' any one answer. That way, you don't inadvertently discourage other would-be answer providers from posting an alternative, and possibly even better, answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A combination of Mico's and David's answers. Look at the final two examples to see why `\left` and `\right` (used in 6) aren't really good.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools,amssymb}

\NewDocumentCommand{\expec}{e{_^}}{%
  \mathbb{E}%
  \IfValueT{#1}{_{#1}}%
  \IfValueT{#2}{^{#2}}%
  \expecaux
}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\expecaux}{[}{]}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather}
\expec{X} \\
\expec_{1}{X} \\
\expec^{n}{X} \\
\expec_{1}^{n}{X} \\
\expec_{1}^{n}[\bigg]{\sum_{k=1}^n a_k} \\
\expec_{1}^{n}*{\sum_{k=1}^n a_k}
\end{gather}

\end{document}
```

[image]

We can also move the `*` or the optional argument just after `\expec`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools,amssymb}

\NewDocumentCommand{\expec}{soe{_^}}{%
  \mathbb{E}%
  \IfValueT{#3}{_{#3}}%
  \IfValueT{#4}{^{#4}}%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{% * version
    \expecaux*%
  }{%
    \IfNoValueTF{#2}{\expecaux}{\expecaux[#2]}%
  }%
}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\expecaux}{[}{]}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather}
\expec{X} \\
\expec_{1}{X} \\
\expec^{n}{X} \\
\expec_{1}^{n}{X} \\
\expec[\bigg]_{1}^{n}{\sum_{k=1}^n a_k} \\
\expec*_{1}^{n}{\sum_{k=1}^n a_k}
\end{gather}

\end{document}
```

Take your pick.

Comment: I was doing a little bit more research on `left` and `mleft` and so on. As far as I understood, there is no easy to way to automatically get appropriately sized and spaced brackets. Is that right? For example, can I make the * version of `\expecaux` use `mleft`?

Comment: @Anvit It does; actually `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` emulates the behavior of `mleftright`, but in an equivalent way.

Answer (score 7):

You can define what you suggest with the `e` argument type, but it might be more natural to define those arguments to come before the main argument, as that's how they typeset. I show both versions here.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts,mleftright}
\NewDocumentCommand{\expec}{me{_^}}{%
    \mathbb{E}%
    \IfNoValueF{#2}{_{#2}}%
    \IfNoValueF{#3}{^{#3}}%
    \mleft[#1\mright]}

  \NewDocumentCommand{\expecb}{e{_^}m}{%
    \mathbb{E}%
    \IfNoValueF{#1}{_{#1}}%
    \IfNoValueF{#2}{^{#2}}%
    \mleft[#3\mright]}
\begin{document}


$\expec{X} + \expec{X}_{1} + \expec{X}_{1}^{n} $

\bigskip

$\expecb{X} + \expecb_{1}{X} + \expecb_{1}^{n}{X} $

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to suggest you make use of the [mathtools](https://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) package (a superset of the `amsmath` package) and its `\DeclarePairedDelimiterXPP` macro.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}   % for '\mathbb' macro
\usepackage{mathtools} % for '\DeclarePairedDelimiterXPP' macro
\DeclareMathOperator{\E}{\mathbb{E}} % unconditional expectation operator
\DeclarePairedDelimiterXPP{\expec}[2]{\E^{}_{#1}}[]{}{#2}

\begin{document}
$\E[g(X)] \quad \expec{}{g(X)} \quad \expec{X\sim F}{g(X)}
\quad \expec*{X\sim F}{\dfrac{g(X)}{h(X)}}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: While in theory this work perfectly, I was specifically looking for a solution that wouldn't force me to retroactively add empty curly brackets in all my previous declarations of `\expec`.